# Where can I get design specifications for phones?

Tags: design

I am designing phone cases for 3D Printing. I am fairly new to the field, however I cannot find design specifications for any phone at all, i.e. exact measurements for the positioning of cameras, buttons, ports, etc. Can anybody recommend somewhere where I can find these documents? Also, if this question is in the wrong forum, can a link to the correct forum be linked please.

Comment: "these documents" ie manufacturing drawings are not publicly available. Overall sizes and photos of the phones from all angles are on most manufacturers websites and would be sufficient for designing a printed phone case. Then email the file to someone with the phone to test fit!

Comment: If you look at most cases - all the holes for ports are slightly larger... guess why.

Comment: Thanks guys for the knowledge, I'll definitely try using the pictures from the manufacturer's website in conjunction with the known dimensions of the entire device. I should be able to resize the pic to those dimensions to aid in the design. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll highly unlikely find any exactly drawings, as mentioned in the comments. These are usually trade secrets. However, you can pull out a caliber and measure the phone you have in mind yourself and make a few prototypes, continually reiterating until you get the results you want.

Classic [Reverse Engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_engineering) :)